# Connected components of Schreier Graph $Sch(G,S,X)$ are exactly the orbits of the action of G on X.

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, connectedness, group-actions

I have difficulty proving a question: 
Let $G$ be a group. $G$ acts on a set $X$, and $G=$ $\langle S \rangle$. 
I am trying to prove that the connected components of $Sch(G,S,X)$ are exactly the orbits of the action of $G$ on $X$. 
***Reminder:*** $Sch(G,S,X)$, also called Schreier Graph, is the directed graph where $V$ = $X$, and $E$ = {$(x,s.x)$ | $x \in X, s \in S $ }. 
I tried to prove it but failed. Both sides are very clear to me, but when I tried, for example, to prove that if $y \in O(x)$ (the orbit of x), then both are connected - I wasn't sure how to continue from that: 
Since $y \in O(x)$, there exists $g \in G$ s.t. $y=g.x$. We can write $g=s_1^{e_1}...s_n^{e_n}$ where for $ \forall i\in[n]$, $s_i \in S$ and $e_i \in$ {$1,-1$}, and then $g=s_1^{e_1}...s_n^{e_n}$.x . Eventually, we need to show that those edges exist in $Sch(G,S,X)$. If $e_i=1$, it is clear, but what if $e_i=-1$? It's not clear for me how to continute from here. 
The other direction of the proof (if both are connected, then they are on the same orbit) is easier to prove. 
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It seems that the question refers to the connected components of the underlying undirected graph, not the strongly connected components. Otherwise I think the claim is not true: let $\mathbb{Z}$ act on itself by addition ($s\cdot x := s + x$), and let $S := \{1\}$, then $\text{Sch}(\mathbb{Z},\{1\},\mathbb{Z})$ is an infinite directed path with no beginning or end, so the strongly connected components are the singletons, whereas the only orbit is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Alternatively, if $G$ is finite (more generally, if every element of $S$ has finite order), replace $s_i^{-1}$ by $s_i^{\text{ord}(s_i) - 1}$.

Comment: Or maybe it is assumed that $S$ is closed under taking inverses. In any case, I think your proof is basically complete, and you just need to read the problem carefully to bridge the gap between what needs to be proved and what you already proved. :-)

Comment: I actually woke up thinking about those two comments of yours! Thank you very much! (:

Comment: Very nice! Maybe you can write up your own answer then. :-) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

There are many options, as @JossevanDobbendeBruyn stated above: 
1) If the graph is not directed, it is clear (since the opposite edges exist). 
2) $G$ is finite, and then we can take ${s_i}^{ord({s_i})−1}$ instead of $s_i^{−1}$. 
3) $S$ is closed under taking inverses. In that case, there is no problem with $s_i^{−1}$, since there exists some $s \in S$ s.t. $s_i^{−1}=s$. 
Thanks again to @JossevanDobbendeBruyn for the help!

Comment: Ah yes, but I was hoping you could tell us which one of these answers solved your issue (assuming you found the problem in some kind of problem sheet / course material / textbook).